# How to make event when I push the button on foreground notification?

Tags: flutter, notifications, foreground

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NOPDi.png)

I'm making timer application.
I want to show the time in notification so I'm using flutter_foreground_task (https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_foreground_task)

I want to stop or reset the time when I push the button on the notification.
How can I do that?

this is my whole code.

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:isolate';
import 'dart:js';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_foreground_task/flutter_foreground_task.dart';

class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomeScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<HomeScreen> createState() => _HomeScreenState();
}

class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {
  void _initForegroundTask() {
    FlutterForegroundTask.init(
      androidNotificationOptions: AndroidNotificationOptions(
        channelId: 'foreground_service',
        channelName: 'Foreground Service Notification',
        channelDescription:
            'This notification appears when the foreground service is running.',
        channelImportance: NotificationChannelImportance.LOW,
        priority: NotificationPriority.LOW,
        iconData: const NotificationIconData(
          resType: ResourceType.mipmap,
          resPrefix: ResourcePrefix.ic,
          name: 'launcher',
        ),
        buttons: [
          const NotificationButton(id: 'stop', text: 'STOP'),
          const NotificationButton(id: 'reset', text: 'RESET'),
        ],
      ),
      iosNotificationOptions: const IOSNotificationOptions(
        showNotification: true,
        playSound: false,
      ),
      foregroundTaskOptions: const ForegroundTaskOptions(
        interval: 5000,
        isOnceEvent: false,
        autoRunOnBoot: true,
        allowWakeLock: true,
        allowWifiLock: true,
      ),
    );

    noticeStart(format(totalSeconds));
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _initForegroundTask();
  }

  static const tenMinutes = 600;
  int totalSeconds = tenMinutes;
  bool isRunning = false;
  late Timer timer;

  void onTick(Timer timer) {
    if (totalSeconds == 0) {
      setState(() {
        isRunning = false;
        totalSeconds = totalSeconds;
      });
      timer.cancel();
    } else {
      setState(() {
        totalSeconds = totalSeconds - 1;
      });
      FlutterForegroundTask.updateService(
          notificationText: format(totalSeconds));
    }
  }

  void onStartPressed() {
    noticeStart(format(totalSeconds));
    timer = Timer.periodic(
      const Duration(seconds: 1),
      onTick,
    );
    setState(() {
      isRunning = true;
    });
  }

  void noticeStart(String initialText) async {
    await FlutterForegroundTask.startService(
      notificationTitle: 'Red Timer',
      notificationText: initialText,
      callback: startCallback,
    );
    setState(() {});
  }

  void onPausePreesed() {
    timer.cancel();
    setState(() {
      isRunning = false;
    });
  }

  void onReset() {
    noticeStop();
    setState(() {
      isRunning = false;
      totalSeconds = tenMinutes;
    });
    timer.cancel();
  }

  void noticeStop() async {
    await FlutterForegroundTask.clearAllData();
    await FlutterForegroundTask.stopService();
  }

  String format(int seconds) {
    var duration = Duration(seconds: seconds);

    return duration.toString().split(".").first.substring(2, 7);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return WithForegroundTask(
      child: Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.background,
        body: Column(
          children: [
            Flexible(
              flex: 3,
              child: Container(
                width: double.infinity,
                height: double.infinity,
                alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                decoration: const BoxDecoration(),
                child: Text(
                  format(totalSeconds),
                  style: TextStyle(
                    color: Theme.of(context).textTheme.displayLarge!.color,
                    fontSize: 68,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            const SizedBox(
              height: 15,
            ),
            Flexible(
              flex: 3,
              child: Container(
                decoration: const BoxDecoration(),
                child: Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: [
                    IconButton(
                      onPressed: isRunning ? onPausePreesed : onStartPressed,
                      icon: Icon(
                        isRunning ? Icons.pause : Icons.play_arrow,
                      ),
                      iconSize: 60,
                      color: Theme.of(context).textTheme.displayLarge!.color,
                    ),
                    IconButton(
                      onPressed: onReset,
                      icon: const Icon(
                        Icons.square,
                      ),
                      iconSize: 39,
                      color: Theme.of(context).textTheme.displayLarge!.color,
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

@pragma('vm:entry-point')
void startCallback() {
  // The setTaskHandler function must be called to handle the task in the background.
  FlutterForegroundTask.setTaskHandler(FirstTaskHandler());
}

class FirstTaskHandler extends TaskHandler {
  SendPort? _sendPort;

  @override
  void onStart(DateTime timestamp, SendPort? sendPort) async {
    _sendPort = sendPort;

    final customData =
        await FlutterForegroundTask.getData<String>(key: 'customData');
    print('customData: $customData');
  }

  @override
  void onRepeatEvent(DateTime timestamp, SendPort? sendPort) async {
    sendPort?.send(timestamp);
  }

  @override
  void onDestroy(DateTime timestamp, SendPort? sendPort) async {}

  @override
  void onNotificationButtonPressed(String id) {
    print('onNotificationButtonPressed >> $id');
    if (id == 'stop') {
      onPausePreesed();
    } else if (id == 'reset') {
      onReset();
    }
  }

  @override
  void onNotificationPressed() {
    // FlutterForegroundTask.launchApp("/resume-route");
    _sendPort?.send('onNotificationPressed');
  }
}
```

I wrote code like this:

```
@override
  void onNotificationButtonPressed(String id) {
    print('onNotificationButtonPressed >> $id');
    if (id == 'stop') {
      onPausePreesed();
    } else if (id == 'reset') {
      onReset();
    }
  }
```

But I got the error like this:
`The method 'onPausePreesed' isn't defined for the type 'FirstTaskHandler'. Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'onPausePreesed'.`

Comment: try to make a minimal reproducible example before posting https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example